# setting delegate to nil to "avoid message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If you have a view controller that implements a delegate, then should you set the delegate to nil when it's deallocated? I get this message all the time.

I am not sure by saying "setting the delegate to nil", what does this mean? Can someone give me a simple example to clarify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely just have to do "SomeObject.delegate = nil" before deallocating SomeObject's old delegate. Can you provide any code snippets from where this warning occurs?

Comment: I am actually getting a very weird error. I have a UITabBarApplication. I tried playing with the apps without changing tabs.. after some time I tried to change tabs and I got a message sent to deallocated instance.. however if after the app launches and I switch tabs I didn't get this error

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to set the delegate to nil before releasing the controller.

It might not be deallocated right away and may accidentally call back to your code which may or may not have gone out of scope -> crash.